# Get all clientID from MCC adwords account by adwordsAPI

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to retrieve all clientID from my MCC account. I'm using this code

```
              AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser(adwordsPropertyService.getEmail(), adwordsPropertyService.getPassword(),
                      null, adwordsPropertyService.getUseragent(), adwordsPropertyService.getDeveloperToken(),
                      adwordsPropertyService.getUseSandbox());

              InfoServiceInterface infoService = user.getService(AdWordsService.V201109.INFO_SERVICE);


              InfoSelector selector = new InfoSelector();
              selector.setApiUsageType(ApiUsageType.UNIT_COUNT_FOR_CLIENTS);
              String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
              selector.setDateRange(new DateRange(today, today));
              selector.setIncludeSubAccounts(true);

              ApiUsageInfo apiUsageInfo = infoService.get(selector);
              for (ApiUsageRecord record : apiUsageInfo.getApiUsageRecords()) {
                      ......
```

But apiUsageInfo.getApiUsageRecords return my only some clientId.
Have you any suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just the list of clientCustomerIds, try ServicedAccountService.
[Here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201502/accountmanagement/GetAccountHierarchy.java) is a code example that shows how this may be done.

Next time, you might also want to consider asking the question on the official forum for AdWords API: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/adwords-api

Comment: The code.google.com link no longer works.

@Anash: Can you post the updated link please.

Answer (score 3):

**My Answer will be helpful for PHP Developers**

I am using v201502(php), You will get all account details from `ManagedCustomerService` api. Please refer the following URL https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/ManagedCustomerService

This is the sample code i used,

```
    function DisplayAccountTree($account, $link, $accounts, $links, $depth) {
      print str_repeat('-', $depth * 2);
      printf("%s, %s\n", $account->customerId, $account->name);
      if (array_key_exists($account->customerId, $links)) {
        foreach ($links[$account->customerId] as $childLink) {
          $childAccount = $accounts[$childLink->clientCustomerId];
          DisplayAccountTree($childAccount, $childLink, $accounts, $links,
              $depth +1);
        }
      }
    }
    function GetAccountHierarchyExample(AdWordsUser $user) {
      // Get the service, which loads the required classes.

      $user->SetClientCustomerId('xxx-xxx-xxxx');
      $managedCustomerService =
          $user->GetService('ManagedCustomerService');

      // Create selector.
      $selector = new Selector();
      // Specify the fields to retrieve.
      $selector->fields = array('CustomerId',  'Name');

      // Make the get request.
      $graph = $managedCustomerService->get($selector);

      // Display serviced account graph.
      if (isset($graph->entries)) {
        // Create map from customerId to parent and child links.
        $childLinks = array();
        $parentLinks = array();
        if (isset($graph->links)) {
          foreach ($graph->links as $link) {
            $childLinks[$link->managerCustomerId][] = $link;
            $parentLinks[$link->clientCustomerId][] = $link;
          }
        }
        // Create map from customerID to account, and find root account.
        $accounts = array();
        $rootAccount = NULL;
        foreach ($graph->entries as $account) {
          $accounts[$account->customerId] = $account;
          if (!array_key_exists($account->customerId, $parentLinks)) {
            $rootAccount = $account;
          }
        }
        // The root account may not be returned in the sandbox.
        if (!isset($rootAccount)) {
          $rootAccount = new Account();
          $rootAccount->customerId = 0;
        }
        // Display account tree.
        print "(Customer Id, Account Name)\n";
        DisplayAccountTree($rootAccount, NULL, $accounts, $childLinks, 0);
      } else {
        print "No serviced accounts were found.\n";
      }
    }

    GetAccountHierarchyExample($user);
```

**SetClientCustomerId** will be the parent ID of your all accounts, It will be appeared near the Sign Out button of you google AdWords account, Please see the attached image

[image]

I hope this answer will be helpful, Please add your comments below if you want any further help